# Gradle exception when switching version from 1.6 to 1.10 in Windows 7 64bit

Tags: java, build, gradle

I download and extract the zip file of gradle to c:\gradle-1.10, and delete gradle-1.6 folder.

And then change the relative Path and GRADLE_HOME in the environment.

And then delete .gradle folder in the home folder

And then try to run gradle command in cmd and I got this:

[image]

I try to google it but there's few information about this error.

However, when I type gradle -v, it's showing the correct content(version number) without any error:

[image]

And when I use gradle in IDE(Eclipse/IntelliJ). It's definitely OK!

Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set `GRADLE_HOME`. You just need to make sure that `C:\gradle-1.10\bin` is on the OS path. Or even better, don't manually install Gradle and use the Gradle wrapper (which is also what the IDEs use by default).

Comment: GRADLE_HOME is just a convenient way to set OS path. I've put %GRADLE_HOME%/bin in the OS path. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Some parties may look for `GRADLE_HOME` specifically, although in general it shouldn't hurt. Running with `--stacktrace` might give additional clues. Also I recommend to use the Gradle wrapper, rather than a manual Gradle installation.